# What is the difference between HTTP parameters and HTTP headers?

Tags: swift, http, http-headers, httprequest, http-parameters

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208463/difference-between-parameters-and-http-headers) question but it didn't answer my question.

To me Headers and Parameters are both dictionaries with the difference that headers is `[String : String]` while Parameters is `[String : AnyObject]?` and so if your parameters are also Strings then you *could* send them within the headers (while using a 'x-' prefix to signify they aren't standard headers) which is a common but not good practice.

- Is that correct?
- Are there other difference between `headers` and `parameters`?
- What kind of other non-String types would you be sending using `parameters`?

**Alamofire `Request` method**

```
public func request(
        method: Method,
        _ URLString: URLStringConvertible,
          parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
          encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL,
          headers: [String: String]? = nil)
        -> Request
    {
        return Manager.sharedInstance.request(
            method,
            URLString,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: encoding,
            headers: headers
        )
    }
```

As an example I have seen people passing `["x-ios-version" : UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion]` or build versions through headers

Comment: The [HTTP spec says](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.3) "The request-header fields allow the client to pass additional information about the request, and about the client itself, to the server." The headers are for meta information about the request that allow the web server to parse the request. On the other hand, the parameters of a request are the actual content of the request. I wouldn't conflate the two just because they both happen to consist of pairs of keys and values.

Comment: @Rob OK. I'm asking what I should do. ALSO I'm asking what others do :) regardless of it being good...So I can understand there code and how other use HTTP headers. So sorry if I'm repeating myself:  *if your parameters are also Strings then you **could** send them within the headers (while using a 'x-' prefix to signify they aren't standard headers) which is a **somewhat** common but not good practice* <-- do some use it this way?

Comment: I really don't understand. You're asking whether you can add your own custom headers with information that really belong in the parameters, even though you know that's not good practice? Sure, but that's a bad idea. If you have an example of a parameter that you're contemplating making a header, please edit the question to include that.

Comment: That's a good example of something that legitimately could be a header.

Comment: @Rob :/ I don't get it! I was expecting you to say it's bad. By what criterion it shouldn't be in parameters? Or it's just a preference and so you won't have to send 2 objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127656/discussion-between-rob-and-honey).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Here is the list of differences:**

1. They are designed for different purposes. Headers carry meta info, parameters carry actual data.
2. HTTP Servers will automatically un-escape/decode parameter names/values. This does not apply to header names/values.
3. Header names/values need to be manually escaped/encoded at client side and be manually un-escaped/decoded at server side. Base64 encoding or percent escape is often used.
4. Parameters can be seen by end-users (in URL), but headers are hidden to end-users.

Comment: So if I wanted to send something in Arabic, I had to use parameters?

Comment: Yes unless you convert the Arabic text to Base64 text - for example.

Comment: Or percent escape it. But whatever you do, you have to manually reverse the process on the server end (where as parameters are generally automatically interpreted by web servers based upon the `Content-Type` header of the request).

Answer (score 36):

The accepted answer is very practical. Make sure you see it. But there are two foundational differences I will discuss in depth:

### Where header and parameters are placed in an HTTP Request

A URL is different from an HTTP Message. An HTTP Message can either be a *Request* or a *Response*. In this answer I will focus on the request. An HTTP Message is just a String with a very specific structure/standard.

An HTTP Request is made up of *mainly* the url, http-method, http-headers (there are other chunks in it, but I'm just mentioning the ones we care about the most)

```
Request       = Request-Line              ; Section 5.1
                *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                  | request-header         ; Section 5.3
                  | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                CRLF
                [ message-body ]          ; Section 4.3
```

A request line is:

```
Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

[`CLRF`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtiBhktB4Qg) is something like a new line.

For more see [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages). You might have to do some back and forth between the links til you get it right. If you really wanted to go deep then see see this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)

So basically a request is something like:

```
POST /cgi-bin/process.cgi?tag=networking&order=newest HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 60
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

first=Zara&last=Ali
```

The [query params](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) are within the URL. HTTP Headers are NOT part of the URL. They're part of the HTTP Message. In the above example, **query params** is `tag=networking&order=newest`, the headers are:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 60
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

So when you make a network request, you're sending a structured STRING using the http protocol. That string is sent through a TCP connection.

### 2 - Why and where one is preferred over the other

From discussion with Rob in chat:

The criteria is that if it's information about the *request* or about the *client*, then the header is appropriate.
But if it's the *content* of the request itself (e.g. what you are requesting from the server, some details that identify the item to be returned, some details to be saved on the web server, etc.), then it's a parameter e.g.:

**Parameter**
Let's say you're requesting an image for a product. The product id may be one parameter. The image size (thumbnail vs full size) might be another parameter.
The product id and requested image size are examples of "some detail" (or parameter) being supplied as part of the content of a request.

**Header**
But things like the request is JSON or `x-www-form-urlencoded` are not the *content* of the request, but meta data about the *request* (especially since it's necessary for web service to know how to parse the body of the request). That's why it's a header.

Most likely if your app makes various requests, its headers would have a lot in common. However the parameters due to the fact that they are content based should be more varied.

---

Construction using `URLComponents`

```
class UnsplashRequester {
    
    static let session = URLSession.shared
    static let host = "api.unsplash.com"
    static let photosPath = "/photos"
    static let accessKey = "My_access_key"
    
    static func imageRequester(pageValue: String, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = host
        components.path = photosPath

        // A: Adding a Query Parameter to a URL
        components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: pageValue)]
        let headers: [String: String] = ["Authorization": "Client-ID \(accessKey)"]
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        for header in headers {
            
            // B: Adding a Header to a URL
            request.addValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
        }
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        }
    }
}
```